# TomCat redirecting to wrong relative URL

Tags: java, html, jsp, tomcat, relative-url

I was working on JSP with Eclipse and TomCat and everything was working fine until suddenly TomCat started redirecting the the wrong address. Instead of "/gestionsueteres/HTML/nuevo.jsp" , TomCat redirects to "gestionsueteres./HTML/nuevo.jsp" (notice the extra period after 'gestionsueteres')

I checked the code and the href is just fine:

```
<a href="nuevo.jsp">Nuevo pedido</a>
```

But TomCat redirects to 404 page.

Going to the file by using http://localhost:8080/gestionsueteres/nuevo.jsp doesn't work.

This is the code from 'ayuda.html' (where I am trying to go out from)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <body>        
       <div class="navbar">
          <a href="nuevo.jsp">Nuevo pedido</a>
          <a href="editar.html">Editar pedido</a>
          <a href="consultar.jsp" class="right">Consultar pedidos</a>
          <a href="ayuda.html" class="active">Ayuda</a>
       </div>
       <div class="descripcion">
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <center>
             <h3>¿Cómo utilizar este sistema de gestión de pedidos?</h3>
          </center>
          <br>
          <br>
          <p>
          <b>Nuevo pedido:</b> Para registrar un nuevo pedido se presiona en la pestaña 'Nuevo pedido', luego
                        se coloca el nombre del cliente. <b>(Nota: No se admiten números ni caracteres especiales.)</b>
           <br>
           <br>
           <b>Editar un pedido:</b> Para editar un pedido, haz click en 'Editar', luego selecciona el tipo de dato que
                        modificarás. Luego pulsa confirmar para enviar los datos.
            <br>
            <br>
            <b>Consultar un pedido:</b> Para consultar un pedido que ya se ha registrado, haz click en la pestaña 'Consultar'
                        y luego introduce la cédula de la persona que vas a buscar.
            <br>
            <br>
            </p>

         </div>
         <div class="footer">
            <h6>Desarrollo de Software IV</h6>
         </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

System details: MacOSX 10.15 Catalina, Eclipse version 2019-09, TomCat 8.5.50

I would appreciate any help.

I attach some pictures for reference:
[Folder I am working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pERER.png)

[Entire Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iKIu.png)

[TomCat error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL5c1.png)